# Numbers 1 gives a total of 603550, but the real total is 563,050

Tags: bamidbar-numbers-book-of, census

I have done some digging and I cannot seem to find anywhere where people try to explain this apparent discrepancy.

Numbers 1 says the total number of Israelites were 603,550. However, if you add up the numbers listed for the 12 tribes yourself, the total comes to 563,050. This is 40,500 less than the total given in the text.

Reuben - 46500
Simeon - 59300
Gad - 45650
Judah - 74600
Issachar - 54400
Zebulun - 57400
Joseph
  Ephraim - 40500
  Manasseh - 32200
Benjamin - 35400
Dan - 62700
Asher - 41500
Naphtali - 53400
*Real* total: 563050

Why is there a difference between the real total and what the text gives as the total? Are the remaining 40500 the tribe of Levi? Or are they proselytes? Is there any way of knowing for sure?

Comment: How sure are you of your arithmetic here?

Comment: I added up the numbers as you give for each tribe and the total is 603550. You forgot to add in Ephraim.

Comment: Shouldn't this question deleted for being factually wrong?

Comment: @Kazibácsi Why is that a delete reason?

Comment: @DonielF If someone can't add up a few numbers that should rather go to Maths SE, therefore it's off topic.

Comment: @Kazibácsi I see this as a question based on a false premise, rather than off-topic.

Answer (score 8):

I think you made a calculation error here, because when I add them up I get 603,550 as the passuk says. Note that 40,500 is exactly the number of people in Shevet Ephraim; did you forget to count them in tallying up these numbers?